# calculate gradient of A * relu(A * X * W0) * W1 w.r.t. A

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, gradient, backpropagation

I'm trying to manually calculate the gradient to do backpropagation for my neural network

the formula for my forward function is  `A * relu(A * X * W0) * W1`

all A, X, W0, W1 are matrices and I want to get the gradient w.r.t A

I'm using pytorch so it would be great if anyone can show how to get the gradient of this function in pytorch( without using autograd).

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK the derivative of the relu function is defined as `df(x) / dx = 1 if x>0; 0 otherwise`. With that it shouldn't be too difficult to get your solution for matrices. Anyway, this question may be better placed at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just a bit of info that may help you: the gradient of a NxM matrix w.r.t. a XxY matrix would most naturally be represented as a XxYxNxM tensor containing the partial of each element of the output w.r.t. each element of the input. Usually in pytorch we are more interested in a gradient of a scalar (loss or objective function) w.r.t. a tensor, which has the same shape as the tensor. Are you sure that the prior is actually what you want to compute?

Comment: Well, yes, my final goal is to get the gradient of loss w.r.t to A but since A is a sparse matrix and I can't get the gradient of sparse matrix as it's described here https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/9674 I was trying to calculate part of the gradient manually.

Comment: the whole function is nll(softmax(A * relu(AXW0) W1) and I can get d/d A * relu(AXW0) * W1 with autograd and I have been trying to calculate d A * relu(AX*W0) * W1 / dA part manually. Do you think this will work?

Comment: @Kai-Eiji I think you may benefit from reading the following document: [http://cs231n.stanford.edu/handouts/derivatives.pdf](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/handouts/derivatives.pdf). It covers general tensor derivatives and describes how you would perform back-prop in a more understandable way than most tutorials I've seen.